# imagick resizing to wrong height

Tags: imagick

I have a 3200x1200 png image

I am trying to resize it to 200x200

I have tried multiple different ways, but it **always** resizes to a height of 75

```
convert -scale 200x200 s.png s.jpg
convert -resize 200x200 s.png s.jpg
convert -geometry 200x200 s.png s.jpg
convert s.png -sample 200x200 s.jpg
```

the width of the resized image is correct, but no matter what I do, the height is 75px.

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
convert -resize 200x200\! s.png s.jpg
```

found here: http://www.imagemagick.org/discourse-server/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=16724

Comment: although this did fix the height, it messed up the width. however, in your link i found the solution by doing  convert -resize 200x200\! s.png s.jpg. thank you

Comment: yeah, I wasn't reading properly, sorry for that :) changed the post to the correct command